# <td> formatting

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, listview, html-table

I have a list view with 10 columns and I want each row to be the exact same size.

The problem is that while the 9 columns are made up of 1-2 words, 1 columns can be made up of an unknown amount of words meaning the format of each row will be different, therefore screwing up the view.

I have tried formatting the odd column's `<td>` like width="200" height="50" style="overflow:scroll" but still, that shows the scrollbars (including on cells which don't need it) and it is actually still expanding the height to accommodate all text (the scrollbars are visible but not usable)

How to format that cell to be the same for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow:auto will only show scroll bars when they are needed

table-layout:fixed will stop your cells resizing

Also overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden for CSS3 depending what support. I know it works on IE8 and firefox, chrome etc. But these allow you to specify just vertical scroll

Comment: Thats the thing it should be needed since I have set the height=50 of each TD and it still expands the height to whatever it takes to accomodate all text. How to actually display text in a TD of 200x50 and have a vertical scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for wrapping the text, the you can do that using CSS. Apply the CSS class to your .

Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line:

```
.wrapText {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

or

```
.wrapText {word-wrap:normal;}
```

normal - Break words only at allowed break points break-word - Allows unbreakable words to be broken

Eg.

```
<td class="wrapText"></td>
```

OR

```
<td style="word-wrap:break-word;"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

First set-up your `table`:

```
 table
 {
  width: 0px;
  table-layout: fixed;
 }
```

The 0 pixel width will be ignored because we'll specify a width for the cells but it's needed to make the fixed layout work (as alternative you may use the right width). Then you have to apply some formatting to the cells:

```
 table td
 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
 }

 table td div
 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

And your cell must be like this:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div>Here the long content</div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have a "table", its a listView <ItemTemplate><tr><td>Text</td></tr></ItemTemplate> so how does it work with that?

Comment: @sd_dracula the ListView does not enclose its content inside anything. If you set the ItemTemplate to use tr then you **MUST** set up LayoutTemplate too!!! (there there is your table). Take a a look here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877898/asp-net-listview-render-thead-tbody-tags

Comment: That must be it. I've changed them in ItemTemplate and ALternatingItemTemplate only. Will try it now

Comment: Ugh its getting frustrating now. Have added the table-layout:fixed to the table in LayoutTemplate and style="height:50px; width: 100px;overflow:hidden;border-collapse:collapse;" to the TDs but it still won't add the scrollbars and just expand the cell to the max height to display all the text.

Comment: From the answer: overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;
This won't add scrollbars (to the cell) but it'll truncate its content to a single line. Where you do need scrollbars? On the cell? on the table?

Comment: Not on the table, just one the one cell which is considerably larger than the rest.

Comment: Can that be affected due to the face the text is inside a Label inside the TD?

Comment: Updated the answer (change overflow mode to what you need (auto or y-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow: hidden to truncate the text when it overflow actual height

Comment: I have tried  <td width="200" height="50" style="overflow:hidden> also and no change. Can anything else be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
​<table border="1" style="height:50px;width:200px;table-layout:fixed">
<tr>
    <td style="height:50px; width: 100px;">
        Test
    </td>
    <td style="height:50px; width: 100px;overflow:hidden;border-collapse:collapse;" nowrap>
        <nobr>  This is a long tex to show how the cell trancate a text, can you see it ?</nobr>
    </td>

</tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Ok that works, now how to make the text scroll vertically? overflow:scroll only makes it scroll horizontally. Also will this work for non fixed tables? Since the table is dynamically created from the listView and it doesnt have a fixed size?

Comment: can you try overflow-y:scroll. and you should be able to set the attribute when the table is being created?

Comment: I have table layout set to fixed where the table is created. And have placed overflow-y:scroll in the TDs, which does actually display the vertical scrollbar but it also expands the cell meaning you can't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around this an asp:TextBox it seems, just created so it looks like a label.
All of the answers above work on an individually created table but I'm just not too familiar with the listView format and probably not setting something somewhere right.